# Python str() double quoted string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I know this question sounds very naive but I am stuck with it. I am using jquery autocomplete and it turns out that it needs ["data1", "data2"] form of list.

I am getting data from a json file and

```
data = json.load(fobj)['content']
data = [str(data[d]['name']) for d in data.keys()]
```

['some text', 'some other '....]

but I specifically want a double quoted string in list. I have tried repr(str(data)) but in it gives "'some text'" and then "'some text'".strip("'") but again this returns a single quoted string.

To get the work done i am doing

```
data = [str(data[d]['name'] + "'") for d in data.keys()]
```

and later process the "'" at the end of string but this is not the right way.

Is there any way with which i can force str() to return double quoted string something like str(data, quote='"').

Comment: Thank you for edit suggestion. I did not post since several months ago and I forgot the formatting rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery means JavaScript. JavaScript literals means JSON. Just re-encode.

```
>>> json.dumps(['foo', '''bar'''])
'["foo", "bar"]'
```

Comment: Oh! and i wasted like 30+ mins on this one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Python single quoted or double quoted strings are the same. For example:

```
a = 'some text'
b = "some text"
```

The reason for having both in Python is because you may have:

```
a2 = 'He said: "Hello!"'
b2 = "It's OK!"
```

Triple quotes are also used like:

```
a3 = """some text"""
b3 = '''some text'''
```

If what you are trying to do is to print somewhere (in a file) a list of double quoted strings, you may do this like this:

```
lst = ['text 1', 'text 2']
print "[%s]" % ", ".join(map(lambda e: '"%s"' % e, lst))
```

Output:

```
["text 1", "text 2"]
```